# dynamics crm. launch dialog process wizard from javascript issue

Tags: javascript, dialog, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, showmodaldialog

I'm doing everything as said in this article http://ankit.inkeysolutions.com/2012/01/crm-2011-how-to-launch-dialog-on-click.html, but the issue is that if I use

```
window.showModalDialog(url);
```

then I can see the following window is open:
[image]

and if I use

```
window.open(url);
```

then dialog wizard is open fine but in new window, not as modal dialog. Any ideas why is it happening?

Comment: rollup version? browser used?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a Chrome browser. From what I've seen Chrome doesn't support modal windows. Try the same in IE.